# jQuery: bind generated elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

thank you for taking time to look at this.

I am trying to code my very first jQuery plugin and have run into my first problem. The plugin is called like this

```
<div id="kneel"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#kneel").zod(1, { });
</script>
```

It takes the first option (integer), and returns html content that is dynamically generated by php. The content that is generated needs to be bound by a variety of functions (such as disabling form buttons and click events that return ajax data.

The plugin looks like this (I have included the whole plugin in case that matters)...

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.zod = function(id, options ) {  

    var settings = {
      'next_button_text': 'Next',
      'submit_button_text': 'Submit'      
    };

        return this.each(function() {        
            if ( options ) { 
              $.extend( settings, options );
        }

        // variables
        var obj = $(this);

      /* these functions contain html elements that are 
      generated by the get() function below */

        // disable some buttons
           $('div.bario').children('.button').attr('disabled', true);

        // once an option is selected, enable the button
           $('input[type="radio"]').live('click', function(e) { 
          $('div.bario').children('.button').attr('disabled', false);
           })
        // when a button is clicked, return some data
           $('.button').bind('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault();
             $.getJSON('/returnSomeData.php, function(data) {
             $('.text').html('<p>Hello: ' + data + '</p>');
           });

    // generate content, this is the content that needs binding...
    $.get('http://example.com/script.php?id='+id, function(data) {
      $(obj).html(data);
    });

  });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

The problem I am having is that the functions created to run on generated content are not binding to the generated content. How do I bind the content created by the `get()` function?

Comment: Might be a typo, but your url doesn't have an ending quote in your $.getJSON method call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find the [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to be useful. They are able to bind events to current and future elements in the document, instead of only documents found at the time of the call.

**EDIT**

Here is a working example of what I mean: http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/39Gt5/ Note that I don't make any further calls to the delegate function, but it is adding new paragraphs and buttons as you click the button, and the click event is automatically bound.

**UPDATE**

For those of you finding this post and using jquery 1.8+, `.delegate`/`.live` have been [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.7/) and replaced by [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). The linked reference shows exmaple of how to convert your code to use the new `.on()` method as well.